# Getting the URL of redirected page in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I need to get the URL of a redirected page in PHP.

Let's say I have an URL like `http://example.com`, while I open this, it redirects to `http://redirected_url.com`. So the input and output of this PHP function must be like this:

- Input: `http://example.com`
- Output: `http://redirected_url.com`

How can I do this?

**Edit:** I don't mean redirection. I need the url of redirected page. So I don't know redirected url, but I need to find it.

Comment: You should clarify your question in the first place ! Also what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried.  You need to clarify which location you are able to edit.

Comment: The PHP function which I need mustn't redirect page. It must just echo the redirected url. like this : echo $output;. So I need to find string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [HTTP response code after redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566225/http-response-code-after-redirect)

Comment: Why was this closed? This is a perfectly legitimate question. This is also exactly what I'm looking for. Also, it is not a "possible duplicate" referred by the comment above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the question, but if you're wanting to tell if a url you're accessing is trying to redirect you, you can use `get_headers("http://some_url")` and check in key[0] of the response if it's sent you a 301 status code.  Or if it has a "location" header like is mentioned above.  [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Like this:

```
function get_redirect_target($destination){
    $headers = get_headers($destination, 1);
    return $headers['Location'];
}
```

I'll leave error (and case sensitivity) handling up to you, but that should get you there

Comment: I don't need it. All the pages which I have are redirected pages. I need to find redirected url.

Comment: There are only two URLs we're talking about.  The one you accessed, and the one it's sending you to.  You have to already have the first one to make the  query, and this method gives you the second.  The "Location" header will contain the url it's attempting to send you to.  If this still isn't what you want, I would advise a complete rewrite of the question since no one is understanding it.

Comment: There can be chains of redirects, too. Also there can be "relative" URLs with redirects. I linked a question [HTTP response code after redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566225/http-response-code-after-redirect) which contains more detailed information.

Comment: Undefined index: Location

Answer (score -1):

```
header('Location: http://redirected_url.com');
```

Comment: It's funny because neither one of you guys got the format correct, according to web standards:  [It should be "Location"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.30) (no downvote)

Comment: As unclear/unresearched as the question is, he's probably right in downvoting this, as it is at least clear that that's not what he was asking.

Comment: I don't mean redirection. I need the url of redirected page. So I don't know redirected url, but I need to find it.

Comment: Good catch, rockerest. John, how do you know that the url has redirected?

Comment: All the pages which I have are redirected pages. So it is not a problem