# Dealing with errors in Fetching JSON files to decode

Tags: php, json, httprequest

I've got PHP5.2 currently.  I ultimately want to use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), to parse the contents of a JSON file obtained via HTTP request.

`json_decode` requires the JSON to be in a string and passed as a parameter, so I'm reading in the file to a string via [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Think of it as:

`$JSON = file_get_contents($URL);`

Where `$JSON` is the storage string for the file contents, and `$URL` is the target URL to fetch the file via HTTP request.  Regarding `file_get_contents` the PHP manual states:

> The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure.

As far as failure goes, I'm assuming this returns `FALSE` on either a timeout (could not reach server at `$URL`), a `404` (reached server, but file did not exist at `$URL`), a `503` (reached server, but was too busy to respond properly), or a `500` (internal server error, generally shouldn't happen).

Anyways, of the errors above I'm most concerned with the `503`, the server I am hitting occasionally throws this on HTTP request.  When this happens, I want to try again.

So I came up with this:

```
$JSON = null; //Initially set to null as we have not fetched it

for($attempt = 0; $attempt < 3; $attempt++) //Try 3 times to fetch it
    if($JSON = file_get_contents($URL)) break; //If we fetch it, stop trying to

//Kill the script if we couldn't fetch it within 3 tries
if($JSON == null) die("Could not get JSON file");
```

This sort of does the job, but I don't think it's very solid.
I was reading more about the contexts, but I don't fully follow how to use them in PHP.  Is there some way I can handle this type of thing in a much better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP creates a variable called [`$http_response_header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) after a `file_get_contents()` call to a URL, you should be able to use this to your favor.

```
function read_json_data($url, $attempts = 0) {

    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    if (!$json && isset($http_response_header) && strstr($http_response_header[0], '503') && $attempts++ <= 2) {

        return read_json_data($url, $attempts);

    }

    if (!$json) {

        throw new Exception("Maximum attempts or not a 503 status code.");

    }

    return json_decode($json);

}
```

Usage:

```
$json = read_json_data($url);
```

Runs up to three times when hitting 503's.

Comment: I'm thinking the `read_data` ought have `json` in there (for recursion).  The concept of `$http_response_header` is what I needed!  I didn't see it obvious on the manual page for `file_get_contents`.  This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a much better way would be to actually take the HTTP status code into account before trying again.

The re-try makes only sense in that specific case you get a `503` but not - for example - a `404`.

---

Similar to the existing answer I'd also say that `$http_response_header` is a good place to fetch the status code from which is fairly easy to capture.

Also you can create the context to specify additional options, you can have `file_get_contents` for example return different than `false` on diverse status codes, too (e.g. 404).

```
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['ignore_errors' => 1]]);

$data = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);

$code = null;

$http_response_header 
    && sscanf($http_response_header[0], 'HTTP/%*d.%*d %d', $code)
;
```

Apart from status-code you might want to check the mime-type that is being returned, you could fetch that from the response headers, too, a function to parse the full array has been outlined in [a related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7566440/367456).