# HTTP response code after redirect to non-ascii domain name

Tags: php, header, non-ascii-characters

How can I get all headers for domain redirecting to non-ASCII domain?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566225/http-response-code-after-redirect)

The domain www.sendevinci.co.il redirecting to non-ASCII domain www.מגשי-אירוח.co.il.

My code is:

```html
$url = 'http://www.sendevinci.co.il';

$options['http'] = array(
 'method' => "HEAD",
        'ignore_errors' => 1,
        'header' =>
          "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" .
         "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n".
                "Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=10\r\n",
                "Connection: keep-alive",
 'user_agent' => self::get_user_agent_string($user_agent),
        "timeout" => 3
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$body = file_get_contents($url, NULL, $context);

print_r($http_response_header);
```

The result is:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2018 13:07:30 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Connection: close
    [5] => X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.6
    [6] => Location: https://www.מגשי-אירוח.co.il
    [7] => X-Powered-By: PleskLin
)
```

The array should include 200 status as well, but it not.

The code works fine for ascii-name domains redirecting to ascii-name domains.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: follow_location should be enabled by default in the context, I would confirm your issue is with the redirect and not the `https://www.מגשי-אירוח.co.il` site.

Comment: I added "follow_location" => true to options, doesn't help

Comment: Well, like I said, I'd confirm the issue is with the redirect and not the site.  Have you tried replacing the $url with the latter site to see if headers are retrieved?

Comment: Did you also try var_dump(http_response_code()); ?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently this is a 301 not a 200

Answer (score 0):

At the HTTP protocol level, a 200 response code with a Location header does not make sense.  You can use a Location header with 201 or 202, but generally, 3xx is used for sending the client to a new location.  I posit that the response you are receiving is correct.  In bullet form, the HTTP location header is valid with:

- 201 - new resource created; get appropriate new location
- 202 - request accepted, still processing, check "here"
- 3xx - general redirection (301/Permanent, 302/Temporary, etc.)

In other words, your assertion that *[t]he array should include 200 status as well* is not correct.  The HTTP status code given by the server in the example is 301.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `file_get_contents` works ONLY with ascii domain names. So there are no simple solution to get all http headers...